# replacing a .gif with individually changing frames

Tags: javascript, function, animated-gif

so basically I'm making a javascript game for a school project & have a simple game which a drone moves around the screen with keyboard keys.
the drone (which I have drawn) i have compiled into a .gif and it works well but when I put it into my game which is coded inside a  element I only get the first frame (as if it was only a .png) so I was wondering how I can either fix it so that it works or break it up into individual .png images and the game puts them together?
this is the code that it needs to be used in;

`function startGame() { 
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(60, 60, "img/forward.gif", 38, 160, "image");
}`

AND its also updated and changed direction in the function Update game area;

```
    function updateGameArea() {

    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -4; ;myGamePiece.image.src = "img/left.gif"; } 

    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 4; ;myGamePiece.image.src = "img/right.gif"; }

    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -4; ;myGamePiece.image.src = "img/back.gif"; }

    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 4; ; myGamePiece.image.src = "img/forward.gif"; }
}
```

Obviously these are just tiny pieces of it and there are other image changes happening too so it can't change anything too dramatically . :) thanks in advance!